# Dynamics 365 - Fields Align in Section Differently in Unified Client Interface vs. Legacy Web Interface

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I am experiencing a behavior change for a section on my form. Currently I have a tab called "Splits" and within that tab is a section called "Quarter Splits" that has eight fields in it. See how the fields are laid out in the form editor and how they are named below.

[image: Layout of Section as it appears in Form Editor]

In the Legacy Interface some of these fields might have values and some do not. For those that don't have any values they are not shown. The fields that do have values will left align. So for instance if Fiscal Year 1 - Q1 and Fiscal Year 2 - Q2 do not have values they will not be shown. Fiscal Year 1 - Q3 and Fiscal Year 1 - Q4 both have values and will be shown. In the legacy interface they will be left aligned as shown below:

[image: Quarter Splits Section as shown in legacy with fields left aligned]

Note in the picture above even though Fiscal Year 1 - Q1 and Fiscal Year 1 - Q2 are the first two fields on the left side in the form form editor since they have no value they are not shown and Fiscal Year 1 - Q3 and Fiscal Year 1 - Q4 are shown in their place.

In the Unified Client Interface this doesn't happen. See below:

[image: Unified Client Interface of Quarter Splits]

In the unified client interface the fields appear in the position were they are designated in the form editor. How can I get the fields in the unified client interface to behave the same way that they do in the legacy interface? That is align themselves to the left of the section regardless of the position they are defined in the form editor?

Answer (score 1):

As you may aware, Unified interface (UCI) is designed for responsive layout to adjust/reflow based on available real estate in various screen resolution, devices, and platforms. Always I have to test for UCI experience across devices, sometimes end up with surprises. So even I have kept two different forms, one for web classic and another for UCI.

But I never tried to hide fields when they are in same row, since usually I put them in a section in single column or two. This way the reflow will be as expected, when multiple sections are in single tab.

Not sure, but what you experience maybe by design or a bug, mostly the former. I recommend you to read [this cheat sheet](https://develop1.net/public/post/2018/04/28/Unified-Client-Form-Properties-Cheat-Sheet) and create a MS support ticket if needed. They can suggest if any legacy form rendering setting can be tweaked in your case.

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for your reply. I did open a ticket with MS support. They confirmed this to be an issue with UCI and a fix will be released on August 18th.